# Is it possible to change elements in Object tag in HTML? If yes, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page where part of its contents is an external web page loaded into it with a HTML object tag like this:

```
<object data="someUrl-on-different-domain-than-host" type="text/html"></object>
```

Now, through jQuery or similar, I want to manipulate the contents of `<div id="mydiv">` in the page that someUrl represents.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Thanks :-)

Comment: It would be possible if you used a `<div>` or an `<iframe>` (assuming the `src` property is pointing to a page on the same domain as the host).

Comment: It's pointing to a page on a different domain :-/

Comment: Then I am afraid that you are outta luck. For security reasons you cannot manipulate the contents loaded from different domains in iframes.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I also thought it might be different because I use the HTML object tag rather than an iframe.

Comment: No, this doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Jquery load

```
$("#mydiv").load("YOUR_URL");
```

your content from provided will be load into this div automatically

**updated**

If you want to get some specific content like a div with id mychilddiv you can do it like

```
$("#mydiv").find('#mychilddiv');
```

Comment: Thanks - and then how would you manipulate the contents in the URL?

Comment: what you wana do with the content? like if you wana get any element from that html you can use find method see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks :)  Just tried it but the external page is not loaded - maybe because it's on a different domain?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, Ramzan. Also thanks to Darin for his comments below my question. :-)